# tkinter: cannot select a directory from my USB connected android phone

Tags: python, android, tkinter, directory, usb

I have developed a simple python app in windows 8.1 with python 3.7

i use: filedialog.askdirectory() and it works well with pc-related directories.

but now i connected my android phone with microUSB-USB, in order to select folders in it, and i cannot see in the navigation any folder, and when I try to select the main, it calls "name not valid"

[in this image, you can see that i cannot select images not on C: or D:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKDgE.png)

Is it even posible to do what I am trying to make?
Thank you very much